# Numeric Soft Keyboard control

Tags: android

I have an EditText control for currency input, however, as everybody knows, Android does not replace the decimal separator in the keyboard like the users locale.

So I'm thinking on creating a dialog to edit this value, like a calculator. This way I won't have an EditText, but a TextView with a numeric soft keyboard.

Do you know any numeric keyboard control that I can plug into my dialog? Or maybe a solution to this Android gap?

Comment: How about creating a custom layout inside a sliding drawer?

Comment: Sliding drawer? Why?

Comment: Because it will show from the bottom like the normal keyboard.

Comment: Give me some time I will give you an answer

Comment: The problem is not how to display the keyboard. The problem is to not have to create a new keyboard or to fix the Android  way of working with decimal values on edittext

Answer (score 0):

For similar problem, I used:

```
android:inputType="date"
```

in xml layout for EditText. This gave me a numeric soft keyboard like calculator. Hope this helps.